# SCRIPT1002: Syntax error in Next JS website in IE11 (getSession)

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, next.js

I am new to NextJS but have managed to make a website that works fine in all browsers except IE11. The issues in the console read....

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
_app.js (20481,19)
```

Which is this _getSession line //HERE!!!

```
var __NEXTAUTH = {
  baseUrl: (0, _parseUrl.default)(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || process.env.VERCEL_URL).baseUrl,
  basePath: (0, _parseUrl.default)(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL).basePath,
  keepAlive: 0,
  clientMaxAge: 0,
  _clientLastSync: 0,
  _clientSyncTimer: null,
  _eventListenersAdded: false,
  _clientSession: undefined,
  _clientId: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2) + Date.now().toString(36),
  _getSession: () => {}  //HERE!!!
};
```

imported from `import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client'`

There a second error:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
index.js (44675,30)
```

Which is this line `var isHTMLElement = (value) => value instanceof HTMLElement;`

Any ideas how I can find the issue to these errors or has anyone come across them before?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try to see the problematic line of code then we can notice that it contains `=> Arrow functions`. [Arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions) not supported in the IE browser.

You need to convert it into a normal function to make it work in the IE browser.

If there are multiple occurrences of this function then you can try to use [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the ES6 code to the ES5 code. This can be an easy fix for the issue.

Here are some reference threads that may give you some additional information.

1. [Why doesn't this arrow function work in IE 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/why-doesnt-this-arrow-function-work-in-ie-11#:%7E:text=IE11%20doesn%27t%20support%20them,Use%20function%20functions%20instead.&text=IE%20doesn%27t%20support%20the,1%20for%20working%20in%20IE%20.)
2. [Syntax error in IE using ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110022/syntax-error-in-ie-using-es6-arrow-functions/40110178)

Comment: It is a node_module so I can't just be modifying that code right?

Comment: I suggest you refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311389/10309381) may help you to know about how to transpile node modules. It can help you to fix the error for the IE 11 browser.